# registerResGeneratingTask, registerResGeneratingTask when sync gradle - onesignal cannot receive pushnotification on android device

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, onesignal

I have trouble with onesignal, unable to receive push notification. I suspect might be this error.

```
> Configure project :app
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

here is thr build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Comment: The appearance of `src/nullnull/release`, `src/nullnull`, etc, should be a hint. What do you have in your `src` folder?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4EmMMtx.png this is src folder. I dont see any nullnull. I even went to command line to list any hidden files.